# How to write test cases for Salesforce application to check its code coverage with an example of making a test case for a code example?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I want to write test classes for my apex code to get code coverage.
I have seen [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) to get idea about test classes but I am not clear about test classes w.r.t my apex classes.
So, I am adding class, one of my code classes and want to get some example test class for this code.
<------ Apex Class ------->

```
public class DataSourceSelector_Apex {

    public List<string> list_string {get; set;}
    public string data_source_string{get; set;}

    public string selected_source{get; set;}

    public DataSourceSelector_Apex(){
        UserConnect_Apex user_connection = new UserConnect_Apex();    
        data_source_string = user_connection.DataServiceProvider;
        list_string = data_source_string.split(';');
    }


    public PageReference QDetail(){
        PageReference pr;

        if (selected_source.equals('Website_1')){
            pr = new PageReference('/apex/website_1_Vfp');
        }else if(selected_source.equals('Website_2')){
            pr = new PageReference('/apex/website_2_Vfp');
        }

        return pr;
    }
}
```

Please give me some example of test class for my code , so that I get whole idea about how to write test classes.

Thanks.
Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE - my testmethod:

```
@isTest public with sharing class Data_Source_TestClass {   
   static testMethod void myTest() { 
     DataSourceSelector_Apex class_test = new DataSourceSelector_Apex();
     class_test.selected_source = 'Website_1'; 
     PageReference pr = class_test.QDetail();
     System.assertEquals('c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/website_1_Vfp';, pr);
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Basic idea is simple -- in your test method you need to create instance of your class, set some properties, execute some methods and see whats a result.
In your particular case, you need to create instance of **DataSourceSelector_Apex**, then set property **selected_source** to some value, like 'Website_1' or 'Website_2' or another string, then execute **QDetail** from your test method, and check if returned PageReference url is exactly page that you need -- like null, website_1_Vfp or website_2_Vfp

Comment: I have followed your instructions and wrote a test classes. i.e.
@isTest
public with sharing class Data_Source_TestClass { 
  static testMethod void myTest() {
     DataSourceSelector_Apex class_test = new DataSourceSelector_Apex();
     class_test.selected_source = 'Website_1';
     PageReference pr = class_test.QDetail();  
      System.assertEquals('https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/website_1_Vfp', pr);        
    }
}

But it gives me errors.. Can you please make it correct.

Comment: what kind of errors?

Comment: what I see from this code -- please, does not check the entire html because it would be different on another environment. you can check if pr.getUrl() contains name of your visualforce page or construct expected pagereference in test and compare their entire URLs

Comment: I think, Its working :)